# Ajax action in Asp.net 5

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

How to write an Action in Asp.net 5 mvc 6, that can handle a http and ajax request?

For instance, I need to render a different view for each request type.

Comment: if your question is how can I detect an ajax request, this code on github has an IsAjaxRequest extension method to do that https://github.com/RehanSaeed/ASP.NET-MVC-Boilerplate/blob/master/Source/MVC6/Boilerplate.Web.Mvc6/HttpRequestExtensions.cs

Comment: Your are correct. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `IsAjaxRequest` property on `HttpRequest` was removed in ASP.NET 5 MVC 6. I wrote an extension method to reproduce this feature (@JoeAudette linked to the code in my project above).

```
/// <summary>
/// <see cref="HttpRequest"/> extension methods.
/// </summary>
public static class HttpRequestExtensions
{
    private const string RequestedWithHeader = "X-Requested-With";
    private const string XmlHttpRequest = "XMLHttpRequest";

    /// <summary>
    /// Determines whether the specified HTTP request is an AJAX request.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="request">The HTTP request.</param>
    /// <returns><c>true</c> if the specified HTTP request is an AJAX request; otherwise, <c>false</c>.</returns>
    /// <exception cref="ArgumentNullException">The <paramref name="request"/> parameter is <c>null</c>.</exception>
    public static bool IsAjaxRequest(this HttpRequest request)
    {
        if (request == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(request));
        }

        if (request.Headers != null)
        {
            return request.Headers[RequestedWithHeader] == XmlHttpRequest;
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to serve a different view depending on the type of request? If so then this should work.

```
public ActionResult DoSomething()
{
    if (Request.IsAjaxRequest())
    {
        //Return ajax view code e.g. return PartialView("_ajax");
    }
    //Return non-ajax view code e.g. return View("nonajax");
}
```

Comment: The Asp.Net 5 does not have the "IsAjaxRequest" function.